# Kafka and Kafka Connect deployment environment

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

if I already have Kafka running on premises, is Kafka Connect just a configuration on top of my existing Kafka, or does Kafka Connect require it's own Server/Environment separate from that of my existing Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, but it runs as a separate process, called a Kafka Connect *Worker*. Except in a sandbox environment, you would usually deploy it on a separate machine/node from your Kafka brokers.

This diagram shows conceptually how it runs, separate from your brokers:

[image: Diagram of Kafka Connect]

You can run Kafka Connect on a single node, or as part of a cluster (for throughput and redundancy).

You can read more here about [installation and configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html) and [architecture of Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/design.html).

Comment: thanks Robin, I cant see that diagram could you try to relink it?

Comment: It's on imgur.com : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhhJ2.png - are you behind a proxy that might block it?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Connect is its own configuration on top of your `bootstrap-server`'s configuration.

For Kafka Connect you can choose between a standalone server or distributed connect servers and you'll have to update the corresponding properties file to point to your currently running Kafka server(s).

Look under `{kafka-root}/config` and you'll see 
[image]

You'll basically update connect-standalone or connect-distributed properties based on your need.

Comment: I'm confused because you say it's just configuration on top of the bootstrap server but then you also mention a Connect server and documentation talks about Connect clusters

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear. You can run kafka-connect in standalone mode or distributed (cluster) mode based on your need on how much data you are processing using connect.

Comment: So am I right in saying:
You need to provision a separate server(s) for Connect and they are configured to work with existing Kafka server.  But bottom line is Connect requires it's own server(s) and it's not just a config file added to the existing kafka server(s).

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct. You kick off Connect as a new process and probably a good idea to kick it off on its own server. However, you can get away with running this process on the same server where your bootstrap Kafka server is running depending on the resources the Connect process will use. Hope this helps. Cheers.